# .NET target framework 7 Web API doesn't respond from Postgresql function using Dapper

Tags: postgresql, function, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper, .net-7.0

I am creating a .NET target framework 7 Web API and I am trying to get data from a Postgresql function using Dapper, but I only get this error :

> 42601: syntax error at or near "getallvendormasternew"
> POSITION: 1

`getallvendormasternew` is a Postgresql function and I have defined this function variable name in the `StoredProcedure` class like this:

```
public class StoredProcedure
{
    public static string GetVendorList = "getallvendormasternew";
}
```

I have called this function as shown here, using `DynamicParameter`:

```
var queryParameters = new DynamicParameters();
queryParameters.Add("_pagenumber", 1);
queryParameters.Add("_pagesize", 10);
queryParameters.Add("_order_by_spec", Convert.ToString("vendorid_DESC"));

return await QueryAsync<VendorModel>(StoredProcedure.GetVendorList, queryParameters);
```

`QueryAsync` is implemented in the `Repository` class like this:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    return (await _db.QueryAsync<T>(sql, param)).ToList();
}
```

Please guide me how to solve this error.

Thanks.

I am trying to get data from postgresql function using above also I have try with add `CommandType` as stored procedure in `QueryAsync` but when I try this, I get an error that this is not a stored procedure because I created it as a function in PostgreSql.

Also I have tried calling it like `public.getallvendormasternew` in the `StoredProcedure` class, but I still get the same error.

I want to know how I can sort out this error and what the issue really is.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont know Postgresql, but since it's a function should you select from it? I would try to do `SELECT getallvendormasternew();`

Answer (score 0):

If I use CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text and pass dynamic parameter in query and create a model of only that fields which is a return from function then I get a data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling a function?

```
return await QueryAsync<VendorModel>(
    "SELECT getallvendormasternew(_pagenumber, _pagesize, _order_by_spec)"
    ,queryParameters
    ,CommandType.Text);
```

Comment: Yes, I have added CommandType.Text and it's working properly.